# How can I fill a unicode symbol in `drawRect` using Core Graphics?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, mask

I know what I want to do, but I'm not sure how to achieve it.  I'm new to Core Graphics and I'm not sure this is even possible.

I have a unicode symbol like this: ♖

The white parts of this symbol are transparent and I'm drawing it in a transparent rect like so:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *textStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    UIFont* myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialUnicodeMS" size:80];

    NSDictionary *attrs =
    @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],
       NSFontAttributeName:myFont,
       NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:textStyle
       };


    [[self getStringForValue:_squareValue] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attrs];

}
```

What I want is to fill the internal transparent sections with white and leave the surrounding rectangle as transparent.

The approach I'm thinking of is using the unicode symbol as a mask in drawRect to divide the rectangle into regions.  Then not filling the region starting at 0,0 but filling all other regions.  Can I use Core Graphics to convert the symbol to a mask and then identify and fill specific regions?

What I'm getting at the moment is this:
[image: no fill]

But what I actually want is this:
[image: with fill]

Comment: Did you research masking? You're on the right line.

Comment: I'm reading Apples docs, I guess I'll find out how to do it there but SO sometimes gives a quick and dirty intro ;-)

Comment: Might help: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/09/creating-alpha-masks-from-text-on.html

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use -[NSBezierPath appendBezierPathWithGlyph:inFont] and then just set the color to white and call -fill on that path.

EDIT: Since you're on iOS, and I don't know how to get the path of a glyph on iOS, instead I'd just draw the glyph to a buffer that's filled with 100% opaque white, and then do a flood-fill starting from 0,0 with pure transparency.

ANOTHER EDIT: With jrturton's code below, you should be able to trivially do a white fill on the path as originally suggested, then stroke it in black.

Comment: That's Cocoa only, though; UIBezierPath doesn't have such a method.

Comment: Those snarfleblatters!

Comment: This category may help for getting the path: https://github.com/jrturton/NSString-Glyphs

Comment: @jrturton - that looks useful, however if you could provide some sample code on how to use it that would be great.  Otherwise I'll try to figure it out, thanks

Comment: @conorgriffin I've updated the README on the repo but there isn't much to it! Hope this helps.

Comment: OK I got it working but I haven't achieved what I want yet.  I've got the `UIBezierPath` for the text character and set the fill colour to black and filled the path.  However, this just gives me a rect with a black character in it, just like I had when I was drawing black text initially without the `UIBezierPath`.  Does the first edit of this answer still apply?  Do I need to create a buffer filled with white, add the `UIBezierPath` created from my string and then do a flood fill from 0,0?

Comment: Make sure your buffer is filled with transparency. I didn't audit this code so I can't promise it works as you'd hope—jrturton would be the one to talk to about that.

Comment: @jrturton - in case the goal I'm trying to achieve isn't clear, in your README example, I would want the rainbow background on your example to be `clearColor` and the inside of the numbers to be a solid colour of my choosing.  However, 4 is a bad example in this case.  The number 9 would better represent what I want where I'd like the circle inside the number 9 to be filled with white and the 9 itself to be black.  I hope that's clearer...

Comment: I just whipped up a test app for this: https://github.com/boredzo/Rook Unfortunately, it doesn't work: glyph shapes are filled, never stroked (stroking replicates the old “outline” text style), so filling and stroking the glyph path doesn't do what conorgriffin wants. Your flood-fill idea is probably the best bet.

Comment: Screenshot of the test app, in case you don't feel like running an iOS Simulator: http://i.imgur.com/vEzcI2A.png

Comment: At this point I'd probably write some code to remove the inner paths from the path you got there. Wouldn't imagine it's too hard to figure out which one is the outermost outline, and just fill that one.